Display not turning on unless bootcamped into Windows
When I turn on my Macbook Pro (i5, 2019) (A2159) the display turns on for a split-second, but then turns off. It only turns on when booted into Windows 10 through Boot Camp, or in the boot menu after ~3 attempted boot-ups. Here is a video showing what I'm describing. https://youtu.be/oFKznOx7_z0 Would love some help here.
Thanks, me :)

What’s the last macOS update you’ve installed to check if there’s a firmware update from Apple?

The last update I installed was the MacOS Sequoia public beta.
